# Assumptions and setting for bayesian mixture model (for RJMCMC)

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gaussian-mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I want to understand about Bayesian mixture model discussed in RJMCMC paper (Richardson and Green, 1997) (https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/article/59/4/731/7083042)
I also posted similar question earlier but with not clarifying my point.
[image]

[image]

Then here is my question regarding that setting.
In the text "In this situation, it is natural to regard the group label z_i for the i th observation as a latent allocation variable. The z_i are supposed independently drawn from the distribution"

1. **Then, how can we understand the meaning of z_i in this context? by Equation (2) p(z_i=j)=w_j, It also implies p(z_i~=j)=0?**
2. In the assumption of model, the observation y_j is determined by w_j*f(.|θ_j) (Eq (1)). **Therefore, isn't y_j should be determinisitic by θ,z,w,k? Then, why we have to consider about the prior of p(y|θ,z,w,k) if it is explicitly determined by θ,z,w,k.**

Thanks for reading my questions. Hope my questions are clarified well in this time.

Comment: This is not a question related to RJMCMC so you should remove the term from the title.

Answer (score 1):

When considering a random variable distributed from a mixture model
$$Y\sim\sum_{j=1}^k w_j f(y|\theta_j)\tag{1}$$
this random variable can be expressed as the *marginal* of a pair $(Y,Z)$ of random variables when their joint distribution is defined as
$$Z\sim \mathbb P(Z=j)=w_j,\quad Y|Z\sim f(y|\theta_Z)$$
for $j=1,\ldots,k$ (the possible values of $Z$).
This can easily be shown as
$$\mathbb P(Y\in A)=\mathbb E^Z[\mathbb P(Y\in A|Z)]=\mathbb E^Z\left[\int_Af(y|\theta_Z)\,\text dy\right]=\sum_{j=1}^k w_j \int_Af(y|\theta_j)\,\text dy$$
for every measurable set $A$. In generative model terms, this means that $Y$ can be generated in two steps:

1. Generate $U\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$ and set
   $$Z=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{when }U\le w_1\\
   2 &\text{when } w_1<U\le w_1+w_2\\\
    & \qquad\vdots \\
   k &\text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$
2. Generate$$Y\sim f(y|\theta_Z)$$

and this leads to the most standard algorithm for generating realisations from (1).

Comment: Thanks for intiutive explanation! I also posted question of RJMCMC rooted from this example (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/625412/jacobian-and-proposal-ratio-of-birth-death-step-in-rjmcmc-of-gaussian-mixture-mo). It would be really helpful if you can give any comments.