# Jacobian and proposal ratio of Birth/death step in RJMCMC of Gaussian mixture model

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mcmc-acceptance-rate, reversible-jump

I am asking questions regarding RJMCMC several times in this site. Some of my questions are answered and some are unanswered. It didn't clarify all of my unclear points but I am glad that I have better understanding of RJMCMC.

I hope this question also help to improve my understanding regarding RJMCMC. I am studying Richardson and Green (1997) paper (https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/article/59/4/731/7083042) of RJMCMC of Bayesian mixture model. The acceptance probability is somewhat simple for birth/death case. Merge/split is more complicated.

[image]

The new parameter w_j*, μ_j*, σ_j* play role as u makes calculation of Jacobian straightforward. However, the calculation of proposal ratio here is not entirely clear for me.
For the birth step, we have to create $w_j*$ and $(μ_j*, σ_j*)$ pair and death step, pair of $w_j*, (μ_j*, σ_j*)$  are deleted.
I guess proposal probability discussed here, the death proposal probability is $d_{k+1}/(k0+1)$ and birth proposal probability is $b_k*g_{1,k}(w_j*)$ which make sense that death probability is computed from k0 which is number of zero component that is allowed to be deleted. and birth probability depend on the distribution of g_{1,k}(w_j*) which can be correspond to the probability of generating certain point of $w_j*$

However, I am confusing that "proposal ratio" of $(μ_j*, σ_j*)$ pair is not included in this equation. New component of $(μ_j*, σ_j*)$ are also generated with $w_j*$ with the some probability distribution and also deleted when one of w_j* is deleted. However, the "proposal ratio" of generating/deleting $(μ_j*, σ_j*)$ is not computed here because they are just generating and deleted randomly? Could you provide some more intuitive explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the birth step, we have to create $_{^∗}$ and $(μ_{^∗},σ_{^∗})$
> pair and death step, pair of $_{^∗}$ and $(μ_{^∗},σ_{^∗})$ are
> deleted.

Correct. However, the probability $A$ in (12) is concerned with the move from $k$ to $k+1$ components, i.e., the birth move, while the death move is by construction (and in order to suit the justification for RJMCMC) completely determined as the symmetric.

> the death proposal probability is $_{+1}/(_0+1)$ and birth
> proposal probability is $_\times _{1,}(_{^∗})$ which make
> sense that death probability is computed from $k_0$ which is [the]
> number of zero [allocation] components that is allowed to be deleted
> and [the] birth probability depends on the distribution
> $g_{1,k}(w_{^∗})$ which corresponds to the probability of generating a
> certain realisation $w_{^∗}$

This is a product of the probability to propose a death/birth move when having $k+1$/$k$ components and of the density of the proposed new mixture, which consists of $1/k_0+1$ for the killed component and of the Jacobian for the renormalisation of the surviving weights, $(1-w_{^∗})^k$, for the death move, while the birth move involves $b_k$ times the proposal density of $(w_{^∗},μ_{^∗},σ_{^∗})$, which is $g_{1,k}(w_{^∗})$ times the prior on $(μ_{^∗},σ_{^∗})$ times again the Jacobian for the renormalisation of the other weights, $(1-w_{^∗})^k$. Hence it cancels in the ratio (12). [Imho, a simpler representation of the moves would be to express the mixture in terms of unnormalised weights divided by their sum.]

> confused by the fact that "proposal ratio" of
> $(μ_{^∗},σ_{^∗})$ is not included in this equation. A new
> component $(μ_{^∗},σ{^∗})$ is also generated with $_{^∗}$ with
> the some probability distribution and also deleted when one of
> $w_{^∗}$ is deleted. However, the "proposal ratio" of
> generating/deleting $(μ_{^∗},σ_{^∗})$ is not computed here because
> they are just generating and deleted randomly?

The reason why the proposal density of $(μ_{^∗},σ_{^∗})$ does not appear in (12) is because *the proposal is the prior*. Therefore the ratio cancels in (12).

Comment: Thanks for very intuitive explanation! Also in the earlier section of paper, _prior on w will always be taken symmetric Dirichlet w|~D(δ+n1, δ+n2,....)_ Therefore, the first line of Eq(12) is the prior of newly added $w_j*$? I am also confused by the appearance of (k+1) multiplication in the first line.

Comment: Also one more question is that if we want to solve problem that ∗ is not need to be normalized. So ∗ can be added by prior distribution and not normalized. And μ∗ is also can be added by proposal, which is same as prior distribution and can be deleted in the same rate. Then, in this case, both (proposal ratio)*(prior ratio) and Jacobian can be 1 (or unity). That can be correct? It might be not entirely clear for this line. I will post another question for the problem I want to solve by RJMCMC